# Dunst progress bar i3 Ubuntu22.04

Tags: notification, i3-wm

I've been experiencing issues with Dunst notifications. Despite setting up everything according to the documentation and troubleshooting as much as I could, I can't seem to get the progress bars to show up in my notifications.

Environment:

```
Dunst version: 1.5.0
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Window Manager: x11+i3
Compositor (if any): picom
```

The progress bar doesn't appear in my notifications with the command in the offical documentation

`dunstify -h int:value:42 "Working ..."`

Here's a bit of log :

```
appname: 'dunstify'
summary: 'Wotking ...'
...
progress: 42
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that my Dunst version (1.5.0) supports progress bars.(Which seems to be the case)

Checked and updated my dunstrc configuration with progress bar settings, including color and width.

Restarted Dunst and even the system multiple times after making

Tested with different notification hints and minimal

Temporarily disabled my compositor (Picom) to rule out any interference.

Ran Dunst with verbosity debug to look for any relevant errors or warnings but didn't find any clues related to the progress bar issue.

Despite these steps, the progress bars still aren't displaying. The rest of the notification appears as expected, and I haven't encountered other issues with Dunst.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on what else I might try to resolve it? I'm open to any ideas, whether it's a configuration tweak, a different approach to debugging, or any insights if you've faced and resolved a similar issue.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide!